# Share circuit breaker over multiple feign clients

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

For an application that has multiple feign clients connecting all to the same external component we want one shared circuit breaker.

How can this be achieved with spring-cloud-starter-openfeign?
[image: overview]

Detailed explanation:

When the providing service is down all 3 clients should stop sending. As all requests should fail. Is it possible that all 3 clients share the same circuitbreaker?

Comment: What library are you using for your circuit breaker?

Comment: Spring-cloud-feign comes with Hystrix

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create FeignClient(not circuit breaker) for providing service(feign in this service).Consuming service inject ‘providing service's FeignClient’, this client can request providing service.

**guides** [spring-cloud-feign](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html) and 
[circuit-breaker](https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/)

Comment: Any example where resilience4j is used with spring-cloud-starter-openfeign?